Should I clean my breakers after a scented oil spill?
I have a unique situation where a diffuser bottle (oil that makes the room smell good) on a shelf above my breaker box fell over and the oil seeped down the wall, including partially into the breaker box. I opened the panel and a few breakers had a little oil on them that I wiped off with a paper towel.
There is no oil anywhere else in the box and I'm fairly certain no oil got towards the back of the breakers, but I’m still concerned about potential fire hazard so out of an abundance of caution I’m considering shutting down the main, taking off the breakers, and cleaning them and the bus bar with a paper towel.
Is this a good idea? Should I use isopropyl alcohol to clean off the oil?

I think you are wasting your time.  You admit the oil was only lightly on the surface of the breakers and you cleaned it off.  You are making up a scenario in your mind that does not exist.  The temperature for a point of combustion for the oil is probably far higher than anything produced in the breaker box.  Any occurrence that may produce a temperature high enough would be a serious issue in itself. You should relax, unless you see oil dripping from the breakers.

I'd be more concerned about the oil physically damaging insulating parts inside the breaker box

I wouldn't recommend removing the breakers and cleaning them off unless you're familar with working on the inside of the panel. Even though you turn off the main breaker in the panel, there is still voltage to the top lugs so be careful. If you are experienced in this, remove a few at the top and inspect them for oil just to ease you level of concern. Just use a dry, clean rag. If, by chance, oil has seeped into a breaker, I'd replace it as oil might cause a premature or a no trip. Don't store stuff above the panel.

No boldfaced warning about flipping the main breaker first and the still hot lugs? What site am I on? :D

@isherwood  I kind of thought that was included in the " if you are experienced in this"  but maybe not.. :-)

The Dunning-Kruger effect is often exhibited here, as elsewhere. To put it another way, a little knowledge is a very dangerous thing.
